# IndexedDB: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb

I just start a indexedDB for my react PWA. And i get this error.

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found. at request.onsuccess`

line is : `const transaction = db.transaction("storeName", "readwrite");`

and the func i did:

```
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const request = window.indexedDB.open("NewApp", 1);

    request.onsuccess = () => {
      if (nameArea && enterDate) {
        const db = request.result;
        const transaction = db.transaction(["apps"], "readwrite");
        const store = transaction.objectStore("apps");
        store.put({ nameArea, enterDate: Date.now() });

        const query = store.get(1);

        query.onsuccess = function () {
          console.log("next info", query.result);
        };

        transaction.oncomplete = function () {
          /db.close();
        };
      };

      request.onerror = function (event) {
        console.error("An error occurred with IndexedDB");
        console.error(event);
      };
    }
  };
```

That problem is in only new opened browser, when i debug it records are adding but not only empty string.

Answer (score 1):

It means either that the object stores have not yet been created, or you are using an outdated db connection.

If the database has been upgraded in another tab, you need to upgrade the connection by re-opening the database in the `versionchange` event.